# Custom Error Pages in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, routes

I need to implement a custom error page in my rails application that allows me to use erb.

I've been following this tutorial (http://blog.tommilewski.net/2009/05/custom-error-pages-in-rails/) and I cannot get it to work locally (or remotely). I am running Rails 2.3.5

Here's the gist of the approach.

1) in the 'application_controller', I over ride the "render_optional_error_file(status_code)" method, and set the visibility to "protected", like this.

```
protected

def render_optional_error_file(status_code)
  known_codes = ["404", "422", "500"]
  status = interpret_status(status_code)

  if known_codes.include?(status_code)
    render :template => "/errors/#{status[0,3]}.html.erb", :status => status, :layout => 'errors.html.erb'
  else
    render :template => "/errors/unknown.html.erb", :status => status, :layout => 'errors.html.erb'
  end
end

def local_request?
  true
end
```

I also created a folder within views called `errors` and created the following views: `404.html.erb`, `422.html.erb`, `500.html.erb`,`unknown.html.erb` and I created a new layout "errors.html.erb"

I can't seem to get it to work.  I've been trying to trigger the 404 page by navigating to `http://localhost:3000/foobar` -- but, instead of getting the new `404.html.erb`, I seem to be getting the standard apache 500 error.  This happens when I try both `mongrel_rails start` and `mongrel_rails start -e production`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I would suggest using exceptions to render such error pages, so you can use inheritance to group your error messages...

First, declare some (I usually do it in application_controller.rb)

```
class Error404 < StandardError; end
class PostNotFound < Error404; end
```

Then add code to ApplicationController to handle them

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  # ActionController::RoutingError works in Rails 2.x only.
  # rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, :with => :render_404
  rescue_from Error404, :with => :render_404
  rescue_from PostNotFound, :with => :render_post_not_found


  def render_404
    respond_to do |type| 
      type.html { render :template => "errors/error_404", :status => 404, :layout => 'error' } 
      type.all  { render :nothing => true, :status => 404 } 
    end
    true
  end

  def render_post_not_found
    respond_to do |type| 
      type.html { render :template => "errors/shop_not_found", :status => 404, :layout => 'error' } 
      type.all  { render :nothing => true, :status => 404 } 
    end
    true
  end
end
```

This renders errors/error_404 with the errors layout. Should get you started :)

And in your target_controller:

```
raise PostNotFound unless @post
```

---

**Edit**

### Note for Rails 3

for a longer explanation on why ActionController::RoutingError doesn't work for rails 3:
[Rails 3.0 Exception Handling](http://accuser.cc/posts/1-rails-3-0-exception-handling).

[Rails ticket 4444](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4444-can-no-longer-rescue_from-actioncontrollerroutingerror#ticket-4444-27)

> "If your application relies on engines that extend your app with their
>   own routes, things will break because those routes will never get
>   fired!"

Comment: Is this correct that the 404 doesn't show up in a development when an incorrect route has been passed?

Comment: Error404 is defined in ActionController, rails itself doesn't generate 404 errors (a static sever might). You should use it like "raise Error404 unless @post" to simulate a static server.

Comment: Just as a side note, `rescue_from ActionController::` does not yet work in Rails 3 for those who stumble upon this post using that version.  See this link: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4444-can-no-longer-rescue_from-actioncontrollerroutingerror

Comment: Thanks for this. Just a thought here - should we actually be rescuing the most specific 404 error first? I would have imagined we'd rescue PostNotFound *then* Error404...

Comment: @Stu: The rescue_from simply wraps ruby's begin..rescue, PostNotFound is a subclass of Error404, so the corresponding method will be called.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly - have you deleted the file: 'public/500.html' If that file exists, it will override anything else that you try to do.

Secondly, using an explicit "rescue_from" in the controller (as explained in the other comment) - is a good option if you need to fine-tune the response to different kinds of errors.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely get the 500 error because of an application error.
Have you checked the log files?

**Update:**

Are you certain that you are running 2.3.5 and not an older version that happens to be installed? 
Mongrel should say which version you are running when it starts, otherwise it should say in the config/environment.rb file.

There are some errors in the code that might create the 500 error. I've changed that and also corrected a few other things I think you meant :)

```
def render_optional_error_file(status_code)
  known_codes = ["404", "422", "500"]
  status = interpret_status(status_code)

  if known_codes.include?(status) # Here it should be status, not status_code (which is a symbol)
    render :template => "errors/#{status[0,3]}", :status => status, :layout => 'errors' # No need to mention ".html.erb", you can do it, but it is not necessary since rails will guess the correct format.
  else
    render :template => "errors/unknown", :status => status, :layout => 'errors'
  end
end

def local_request?
  # This must return false instead of true so that the public viewer is called 
  # instead of the developer version.
  false 
end
```

Comment: what I'm saying is that this application error is caused by the rooting error

Comment: ok you're right! I removed my question since it wasn't accurate anymore and I'm really not sure what's the OP's problem. Thanks for the enlightment ^^

Comment: yes, I appear to be getting a routing error ...

here's what I see when I tail the dev logs;

Processing ApplicationController#index (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-02-10 12:35:35) [GET]

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/foobar" with {:method=>:get}):
  

Rendering rescues/layout (not_found)
/!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Wed Feb 10 12:35:35 -0500 2010
  Status: 500 Internal Server Error

how can I fix this? And subsequently test to see if it's working?

Comment: hmm, have you corrected the paths as I've suggested?

I believe that it is something in that method that is triggering the 500 error. I am not certain on why you don't get a trace of it, but it is probably because that method is supposed to handle it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Purpose of completeness for newer rails versions:

http://www.frick-web.com/en/blog/nifty_errorpages-gem

that is a little rails engine for handling your error pages. Maybe you will need it for newer projects. it is a good option to handle errors in my opinion.