# Can some one explain the code snippet given below in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  class InvalidParam < StandardError;end
end
```

What is the reason for including another class inside application controller??
What will be the behavior for other controllers?

Comment: I found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238244/custom-error-pages-in-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Adding Semantics - Private exceptions v System generated exceptions

There's no structural difference between InvalidParam and StandardError - I'm betting that the developer is layering his/her own semantics on InvalidParam. That's naughty because it will just confuse the reader.

The code declares a nested class called InvalidParam for the purposes of Exception handling. The developer wants to be able to raise and rescue exceptions with InvalidParam rather than StandardError - most likely because they want to distinguish between system exceptions and their own.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be declaration of nested class that will not be used anywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for including another class inside application controller is that the class will be visible only inside the controller (scoping). Other controllers will not be influenced.

Comment: clyfe, class InvalidParam is inheriting StandarError( it is a stub). What will this line of code will do ? why it is written inside application_controller? If you  could explain that point it will really help me out.