# jqgrid : Validate on serverside for editing a row

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I am using Jqgrid with MVC2. It looks like the grid doesn't care for server side validation, say we need to save the data to Database and there is a error while inserting data.

We need to be able to show an error message saying there is error while edit at server level, is it like possible? Any examples/comments?

Comment: Which editing mode you use (inline editing, form editing or cell editing)? Because use ask about editing a **row** it is probably not cell editing, but which one: form or inline editing?

Comment: inline editing is what I am using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you that the server return allays an error HTTP code in case of validation error or any other errors (see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668167/prevent-restoring-row-if-error-was-rised-while-editing/4668387#4668387) for more information). In the case you should use `errorfunc` parameter of the [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow) function and not the `succesfunc`. It is the common rule. So I recommend you to define [loadError](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) event handler in **every** jqGrid which get any data from the server. In the same way you should use [errorTextFormat](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing) in case of form editing and [errorCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing#events) in case of cell editing.