# jqgrid save method send validation message back to grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a jqgrid in MVC. It has a save method specified as:

```
editurl: '/Invoice/SaveInvoiceLine/',

public void SaveInvoiceLine(InvoiceLine invoiceLine)
        {
            ...
        }
```

What I want to do is do some last minute validation in here. There decide whether to save or not. That will be easy enough. The problem is though if I don't decide to save how do I get a validation message back to the grid to show the reason why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just use `errorfunc` parameter of the [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow) method. The second parameter of the `errorfunc` callback function is the response from the server. It's `responseText` property is the text of the response.

If the server response from the `editurl` returns any error HTTP code the `errorfunc` callback function will be called instead of the standard editing processing.

See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217630/jqgrid-inline-edit-how-to-save-again-if-post-returns-error/6218257#6218257) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668167/prevent-restoring-row-if-error-was-rised-while-editing/4668387#4668387) for additional information.